# Filter a datatable with specific values

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, excel-tables, listobject

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets.

A sheet named "Items" contains a single column table named "ItemsTable" with a number of entries. It doesn't matter how many.
I added a button "Filter" next to it for later use:
[Items sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Irov.png)

Secondly I have a sheet named "Data" which has a table named "DataTable".  In this table I added entries from the ItemsTable randomly (each cell is a dropdown list where I can choose an entry from the ItemsTable). There can be blank cells.
[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Xu9.png)

So far for the available data. I want to do some extracting of data from here on.
First I manually filter some items on the "Items" Sheet, for example only pear and banana this time:
[Items sheet filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqvfT.png)

When I click the "Filter" button, it should take the selected items (two in this case) and check if these are present at the same time on the rows of the DataTable.
They both (or however many items I chose) have to be present on a row, in any order.
The idea is to create a new sheet called "Stats" (or delete the content if this sheet already exists) and create a table on that sheet with the same headers as the "DataTable" table and add all rows that fit the criteria to that newly created table.

So in this case the "Stats" sheet would be created (or cleared of content if it exists) and a table should be added with the following rows:
[Stats sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLCS0.png)

I want VBA code for this Filter button:

```vb
Sub Filter()

End Sub
```

I tried using arrays and loops but I run into several issues each time.
I ran into issues trying to use only the selected items that I filtered using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.
I will not paste code I tried as it will probably be useless.

Comment: in your stat sheet example shouldn't it also include row 3 with apple, pear from the data sheet? because it  also includes pear based on your filtered items sheet

Comment: No as I filtered on pear and banana. ALL filtered items have to be present on a row, not any single one. They all have to be there or the row is not taken into account. In this case all rows that have pear AND banana need to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP BY STEP in one sub

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub doTheCopy()
   Dim datat As ListObject, vis As Range, ar As Range, tar As Range
   Dim statWs As Worksheet, dataWS As Worksheet
   Dim lbr As Long, ubr As Long, lbc As Long, ubc As Long, rr As Long, cc As Long, fcnt As Integer, haveToFind As Integer
   Dim arr() As Variant, ln() As String, filterdStr As String, strRowsToCopy As String
   Const char160 = " "
   
   'FIND THE VISIBLE AREA
   Set vis = Me.ListObjects("ItemsTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   If vis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   
   'GET THE TWO OTHER SHEETS
   On Error Resume Next
   Set dataWS = Worksheets("Data")
   Set statWs = Worksheets("Stats")
   If dataWS Is Nothing Then GoTo Lexit
   Err.Clear

   'IF STATS SHEET DON'T EXIST => CREATE IT
   If statWs Is Nothing Then
      Set statWs = Worksheets.Add(, dataWS)
      If statWs Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("Can't create Stats Sheet"): GoTo Lexit
      statWs.Name = "Stats"
   End If

   'AFTER THIS POINT I DONT NEED RESUME NEXT
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lexit

   'GET DataTable
   Set datat = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("DataTable")

   'POSITION IN STAT SHEET TO COPY THE TABLE => "A1"
   Set ar = statWs.Range("A1")
   
   'COPY THE TABLE AND NAME IT - CLEAR TABLE CONTENTS TO BE READY FOR COPY - IF NOT EXIST
   If ar.ListObject Is Nothing Then
      datat.Range.Copy ar
      ar.ListObject.Name = "StatTable"
   End If
   if Not ar.ListObject.DataBodyRange is Nothing Then
      ar.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
   End If

   'MAKE A STRING WITH VALUES TO FIND, COUNT THEM
   filterdStr = char160
   For Each tar In vis
      For cc = 1 To tar.CountLarge
         If tar(cc) <> vbNullString Then
            filterdStr = filterdStr & tar(cc) & char160
            haveToFind = haveToFind + 1
         End If
      Next
   Next
   
   'SCAN LINE BY LINE THE TABLE AND IF TAKE -haveToFind- MATCHES THEN
   'ADD THE LINE NUMBER IN STRING
   arr() = datat.DataBodyRange
   ubr = UBound(arr, 1):   lbr = LBound(arr, 1)
   ubc = UBound(arr, 2):   lbc = LBound(arr, 2)
   For rr = lbr To ubr
      fcnt = 0
      For cc = lbc To ubc
         If arr(rr, cc) <> vbNullString Then
            If InStr(1, filterdStr, char160 & arr(rr, cc) & char160) > 0 Then fcnt = fcnt + 1
            If fcnt = haveToFind Then
               strRowsToCopy = strRowsToCopy & IIf(strRowsToCopy = vbNullString, "", " ") & rr
               GoTo LnextRow
            End If
         End If
      Next
LnextRow:
   Next

   'IF HAVE LINES TO COPY
   If strRowsToCopy <> vbNullString Then
      'SPLIT TO TAKE THE LINE NUMBERS
      ln = Split(strRowsToCopy)
      fcnt = 1
      'COPY THE LINES FROM SOURCE TABLE TO DESTINATION
      ubr = UBound(ln)
      For cc = LBound(ln) To ubr
         rr = Val(ln(cc))
         ar.ListObject.ListRows.Add
         datat.ListRows(rr).Range.Copy ar.ListObject.ListRows(fcnt).Range
         fcnt = fcnt + 1
      Next
   End If
Lexit:
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("doTheCopy>" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number> " & Err.Number)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub BT_FILTER_ITEMS_Click()
   Call doTheCopy
End Sub
```

**SECOND modified VERSION WITH EXACT SEARCH

and look in colums whose headers begin with**

```
Option Explicit

'*****************PARAMETERS**************************************
' exact> for exact search (true) else (false)
' copyAtCell> the position (a cell) in any sheet to create the stat table
' Optional lookHeadersStartWith> look at columns whose headings
'          begin with "Item" (default) or any other string.
'          The comparison is case insensitive (in the comparison spaces are cut off)
'*****************************************************************
Private Sub doTheCopy(exact As Boolean, copyAtCell As Range, Optional lookHeadersStartWith As String = "ITEM")
   Dim datat As ListObject, vis As Range, tar As Range
   Dim statWs As Worksheet, dataWS As Worksheet, statTbl As ListObject, lr As ListRow
   Dim lbr As Long, ubr As Long, lbc As Long, ubc As Long, rr As Long, cc As Long, fcnt As Integer, haveToFind As Integer
   Dim arr() As Variant, hdr() As Variant, ln() As String, filterdStr As String, strRowsToCopy As String
   Const char160 = " "
   
   If copyAtCell.CountLarge > 1 Then Set copyAtCell = copyAtCell.Cells(1, 1)
   'FIND THE VISIBLE AREA
   Set vis = Me.ListObjects("ItemsTable").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   If vis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   
   'GET THE TWO OTHER SHEETS
   On Error Resume Next
   Set dataWS = Worksheets("Data")
   Set statWs = Worksheets("Stats")
   If dataWS Is Nothing Then GoTo Lexit
   Err.Clear

   'IF STATS SHEET DON'T EXIST => CREATE IT
   If statWs Is Nothing Then
      Set statWs = Worksheets.Add(, dataWS)
      If statWs Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("Can't create Stats Sheet"): GoTo Lexit
      statWs.Name = "Stats"
   End If

   'AFTER THIS POINT I DONT NEED RESUME NEXT
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lexit

   'GET DataTable
   Set datat = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("DataTable")

   'POSITION IN STAT SHEET TO create stats table => copyAtCell
   'if in position (copyAtCell) exist any table delete it
   If Not copyAtCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
      copyAtCell.ListObject.Delete
   End If
   
   'create new table at position (copyAtCell) with equal number of columns
   Set statTbl = copyAtCell.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, copyAtCell.Resize(1, datat.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count), , xlYes)
   'can now give it a name for further reference
   statTbl.Name = "STAT_TABLE"
   'copy headers from DataTable
   datat.HeaderRowRange.Copy copyAtCell

   'MAKE A STRING WITH VALUES TO FIND, COUNT THEM
   filterdStr = char160
   For Each tar In vis
      For cc = 1 To tar.CountLarge
         If tar(cc) <> vbNullString Then
            filterdStr = filterdStr & tar(cc) & char160
            haveToFind = haveToFind + 1
         End If
      Next
   Next
   
   'SCAN LINE BY LINE THE TABLE AND IF TAKE >= -haveToFind- MATCHES THEN
   'ADD THE LINE NUMBER IN STRING
   arr() = datat.DataBodyRange
   hdr() = datat.HeaderRowRange
   ubr = UBound(arr, 1):   lbr = LBound(arr, 1)
   ubc = UBound(arr, 2):   lbc = LBound(arr, 2)
   For rr = lbr To ubr
      fcnt = 0
      For cc = lbc To ubc
         If arr(rr, cc) <> vbNullString And InStr(1, UCase(Trim(hdr(1, cc))), lookHeadersStartWith) = 1 Then
            If InStr(1, filterdStr, char160 & arr(rr, cc) & char160) > 0 Then
               fcnt = fcnt + 1
            Else
               If exact Then GoTo LnextRow
            End If
            If fcnt = haveToFind And exact = False Then
               GoTo LfoundOneRow
            End If
         End If
      Next
      If exact = True And fcnt >= haveToFind Then
LfoundOneRow:
         strRowsToCopy = strRowsToCopy & IIf(strRowsToCopy = vbNullString, "", " ") & rr
      End If
LnextRow:
   Next

   'IF HAVE LINES TO COPY
   If strRowsToCopy <> vbNullString Then
      'SPLIT TO TAKE THE LINE NUMBERS
      ln = Split(strRowsToCopy)
      fcnt = 1
      'COPY THE LINES FROM SOURCE TABLE TO DESTINATION
      ubr = UBound(ln)
      For cc = LBound(ln) To ubr
         rr = Val(ln(cc))
         'If statTbl.ListRows.Count < fcnt Then
          Set lr = statTbl.ListRows.Add
         'End If
         datat.ListRows(rr).Range.Copy lr.Range       'statTbl.ListRows(fcnt).Range
         fcnt = fcnt + 1
      Next
   End If
Lexit:
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("doTheCopy>" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number> " & Err.Number)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub BT_FILTER_ITEMS_Click()
   Call doTheCopy(Me.ExactSearch.value, Worksheets("Stats").Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to change Me.ListObjects to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Items").ListObjects as it gave an error using Me. After that it worked correctly! The only thing is that it leaves the dimensions of the Stats table identical to the Data table, so if there are less results there are a lot of empty rows at the bottom of the Stats table. How can I resize this table so there are no empty rows at the bottom?

Comment: Is easier to delete the DataBodyRange and add line before copy. I modify the code. The code uses "Me" because is in the Sheet "items" module. The code is called from the button click, the physical plase to live is the "items" module.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!
I added 1 more thing and that is a checkbox named "ExactSearch". With the code so far when it filters on the selected items, it saves the rows where those are present, even if there are other items present, which I meant it to be. But there are situations where I want to save only the rows that contain exactly those items with all other item fields blank. That's why I added this checkbox. When I check it, I would like it to search only for this exact combination, with no other items on that row, the rest of the item fields should be blank. Is that a lot to add to this code?

Comment: It is easy, just need the parameter when call the sub and the extra code: Else
               If exact Then GoTo LnextRow

Comment: Something is still not correct when I use the code with "exact search". Try with using as filter apple and banana and with these entries in the data table with 4 item columns: Row 1 (apple-blank-banana-pear) and Row 2 (banana-blank-apple-blank). When using exact search I should only get row 2 as a result, being the 2 hits from the filter and the rest blank, so an exact match. But running your exact search I get both these rows :)

Comment: Yes, need correction. Q: if using as filter apple and banana, then a line with: banana-blank-apple-banana is valid to copy?

Comment: Yes that is allowed! But no other items should be on that row. I see you already altered the code a bit, it gives me an empty table as a result with "exact match" checked. But I guess you're still looking at it :)

Comment: I see why I get an empty table. The Results column is always filled in with "Win" or "Loss". The code views this as a non-match and as a result neglects the row as a result, even though there is only apple and banana on it, combined with win/loss. I'll check if I can add a condition so that it doesn't use the last column "Results" to dismiss a result.

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution, but I changed the for loop statement to "For cc = lbc To ubc - 1" and that did the trick. It would be cleaner if it only included columns with a header named "Item x" but ok, it works now. If you have a better solution than my "-1" trick, feel free to adjust it. I'm really grateful for your help, you're a lifesaver so thx a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

### Retrieve Filtered Data

[image]

```vb
Sub RetrieveFilterData()
 
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Lookup
    Const LKP_SHEET As String = "Items"
    Const LKP_TABLE As Variant = 1 ' or e.g. "Items"
    Const LKP_COLUMN As Variant = "Items"
    ' Source
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Data"
    ' Destination
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Stats"
    Const DST_TABLE As String = "Stats"
    Dim dColumns(): dColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
 
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the lookup range (the filtered rows in the lookup column).
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets(LKP_SHEET)
    Dim llo As ListObject: Set llo = lws.ListObjects(LKP_TABLE)
    Dim llc As ListColumn: Set llc = llo.ListColumns(LKP_COLUMN)
    Dim lrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set lrg = llc.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    ' Delete the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Copy the source as the destination worksheet.
    
    sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    dws.Name = DST_SHEET
    ' Assuming the 1st source or destination table:
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(1)
    dlo.Name = DST_TABLE
    ' Clear filters.
    If dlo.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If dlo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
            dlo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If
    
    ' If nothing was filtered.
    
    If lrg Is Nothing Then
        dlo.DataBodyRange.Delete
        MsgBox "Nothing to lookup.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Write the filtered strings to a dictionary.
    
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        
    Dim lCell As Range, lStr As String
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        lStr = CStr(lCell.Value)
        If Len(lStr) > 0 Then
            If Not lDict.Exists(lStr) Then
                lDict(lStr) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next lCell
        
    If lDict.Count = 0 Then
        dlo.DataBodyRange.Delete
        MsgBox "Only blanks found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Write the source or destination data to an array.
        
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dlo.DataBodyRange
    Dim dData(): dData = drg.Value
    
    ' Write the matching data to the top of the array.
    
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(dColumns)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(dData, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(dData, 2)
    
    Dim lKey, r As Long, dr As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim dStr As String, IsNotFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For Each lKey In lDict.Keys
            For n = 0 To nUpper
                c = dColumns(n)
                dStr = dData(r, c)
                If StrComp(dStr, lKey, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
            If n > nUpper Then
                IsNotFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lKey
        If IsNotFound Then
            IsNotFound = False
        Else
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = dData(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
                
    If dr = 0 Then
        dlo.DataBodyRange.Delete
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the matching data from the top of the array
    ' to the destination table.
    
    drg.Resize(dr, cCount).Value = dData
    
    ' Delete the remaining (table) rows.
    
    If dr < rCount Then
        drg.Resize(rCount - dr).Offset(dr).Delete xlShiftUp
    End If

    ' Inform.
   
    MsgBox "Filtered data retrieved.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Needs some explanation.

Comment: Works great thanks! I would like to be able though to add more item columns in the data table. If I add a column with "Item 5" the code no longer works. I presume this is because of:
Dim dColumns(): dColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4).

Is it possible to change it so it checks how many item columns there are? In that case it always works no matter how many Item columns I use.